# Catch 400 error in expressJs due to exceed request header

Tags: node.js, express, bad-request

I have a web application written in nodejs and expressjs.
My application has many cookies for different businesses, 
recently i get 400 error because of the length of request header.
for every request these many cookies are sent to server.
I want to catch 400 error in expressJs and want to delete the cookies.
Is this a good way to fix this bug ?

this is my app.js file :

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import WebSettings from "core/settings/webSettings";
import express from "express";
import yields from "express-yields";
import open from "open";
import homeController from "ui/web/controllers/homeController";

const port = process.env.PORT || WebSettings.port;
const app = express();

app.get("/", function* (req, res) {
});

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        open(`http://localhost:${port}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try this https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html ?

Comment: yes, it is not working.